# Angular2 and cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-cli

I have some notice code like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" [ngClass]="{hidden: showBanner('some-value')}">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" (click)="hideBanner('some-value')">&times;</button>
    <strong>NOTICE:</strong>  Some notice text... 
</div>
```

When a user closes this notice I set a cookie and when the page loads, I check to see if a cookie has been previously set before displaying it.

```
showBanner(value)
{
   return (Cookie.check(value)) ? true : false;
}

hideBanner(value)
{
    Cookie.set(value,'true',new Date().setFullYear(2300,1,1));
    var cookies = Cookie.getAll();
    Object.keys(cookies);
}
```

When I check the cookie in the browser it shows it as being set as a "session" cookie and not as a date based cookie.

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Why not use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead of cookies?

Comment: Thanks - I did that instead and it was a whole lot less pain.

Comment: @HappyCoder if you found a solution, you should answer and accept for this question.

Comment: I used browserStorage to resolve this as per this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043205/angular-cli-best-way-to-manage-notices/43072258#43072258).